# How to declare parameters (which depend on one another ) in C

Tags: c, parameters

I have a bunch of parameters (integers and floats); I want to write a C code where both the main program and the functions refer to the same parameters so that if I change one of them the whole code knows the new value I set. My code is formed by a main.c file which calls a function.c file; right now I declared the parameters both in the main and in the function but I think that is not robust (if I change one parameters in the main and I forget to change it also in the function I get wrong results). So here is the question: How can declare the parameters in order to change it just once and not to change it everywhere I have defined?

PS: some of the parameters depend from some others that have been previously declared

Here's what I did: I created a `myparameters.h` file where I declare my parameters like this: `extern float x;`
then I created a `myparamter.c` file where I define the value of the parameter: `float x = 10;`

However some of the parameters I define depend from others: `float a = a + b`; and therefore I get an error message like this one:

> warning: initializer element is not a constant expression

Comment: mmm... I already have... let me edit the question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Terminology Clarification

What you're talking about are **global variables**, not **parameters**. The word "parameters" refers to input arguments to a function:

```
int my_function(int arg1, char arg2) {
```

That is how you should be passing arguments to your functions, not through global variables.

### Your Error

You're getting the error because you're trying to initialize a global variable outside of a function with a value that is not necessarily known at compile time:

```
int a = 2;     /* legal */
int b = a + 2; /* not legal */

int main(){ /* the rest of your code */
```

Globals can only be initialized by constants, macros, and hardcoded values:

```
int a = 2; /* legal */
int b;     /* also legal */

int main(){
    b = a + 2; /* now that you're in a function, you can make your assignment */
```